# 5 PRs I want to test locally, confused about git commands

Tags: git, github, git-checkout

3 months ago, 5 PRs were merged into our repository.

One of these PRs is causing an issue.

I wish to roll back to when each PR was merged, test locally, and isolate the issue down to the one problematic PR. I do not want to commit anything to master.

So my plan to go to each PR, find the final commits SHA and run :

```
git checkout <SHA> #checks out/downloads all work up to commit id, discards any commits made after this date locally
git checkout -b bugIsolation
```

Will this work as I hope/is there a cleaner or better way to do this?

Comment: You can just checkout by the revision id and test there, no need to create a branch there... just checkout each branch or revision, test there, checkout the next one and so on.... when you want to come back to where you were when you started, just checkout the right branch and you are done,

Comment: Yes, no need to create a branch immediately if you merely inspect.

Comment: Thanks for the support, @RomainValeri I know I can always count on you :-D coming back: now, if you wanted to create a revision from that revision you checked out, then you might consider creating a branch so you can then push, create a PR, you know, the whole workflow for github

Comment: Note that checking out an old commit by hash ID doesn't *discard* subsequent commits. They still exist. You can still find them: all you need is to know the hash IDs of those commits. The Git repository is, to a large extent, just a big database of commits, keyed by hash IDs. The trick is finding the hash IDs. Since your question isn't about finding the hash IDs, there's no need to go into details here.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that `git bisect` is the tool that you're looking for. It'll slightly different thing that you've described. The command use binary search to find *the commit* that introduced the bug, instead of checking out stuff several times manually as you described I would instead:

```
git bisect start
git bisect good <good revision>
git bisect bad <bad revision>
```

After those commands `git` would tell you something along the lines:

```
Bisecting: N revisions left to test after this (roughly M steps)
[d4a69a45398cf729c089087030da7d7a7a088802] <commit message>
```

Git will automatically checkout „middle” commit between `<bad revision>` and `<good revision>`. Now it's your turn to verify if the current revision is valid or not.

When you find out that the current revision is bad you're telling git about it with `git bisect bad`. If the current revision is good you're using `git bisect good`. That behavior repeats until you find a single commit that introduced the bug.

There is also an option to automate the checking process – `git bisect run` is meant for that.

When you're done and  you've found the bad commit you're using `git bisect reset` which would checkout the revision from which you've started bisect.